# vim start file with parameter which executes on the whole file

Tags: csv, vim, command-line, parameters, vim-plugin

I use the [csv.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2830) plugin. When I start a csv file, the plugin does his job. Often I need the command`:ArrangeColumn`, which acts on the current line off the cursor. To arrage the whole file i select everything and run the command.

Now I want to have this always when I open a csv file. I looked at `modelines` as an option, but there you can only set options. Its not possible to call commands.

The other alternative would be to start the csv file with paramter `-c`, but there I do not know how to select the whole file to run the command `:ArrangeColumn`

```
gvim -c :ArrangeColumn foo.csv # Arranges the first line
```

I usually do this with `:%s`, but this does not work?

```
gvim -c %sArrangeColumn foo.csv # will clearly will not work....
```

**How can I start a csv file and initally call the command`:ArrangeColumn` on the complete file?**

Comment: `vim -c %ArrangeColumn foo.csv` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. In `:%s`, the `%` is the *range* (a shortcut for `1,$` addressing the entire buffer), and `s[ubstitute]` is the command. As `:ArrangeColumn` also takes a range, you can prepend `%` just as well:

```
gvim -c %ArrangeColumn foo.csv
```

For more information, see `:help :range`.

#### Alternative

If you want to do this for *all* CSV files, you can create a script `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/csv.vim` with the following contents:

```
%ArrangeColumn
```

This will execute *after* the `csv.vim` plugin and apply the command to each opened CSV buffer. You could additional wrap the command with a `if expand('%') =~ '...'` condition to apply this only to certain CSV files.

Comment: the `%ArrangeColumn` works fine when I use it in vim, but when give as startup parameter it has the same effect like without `%`... sadly. `The ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/csv.vim` works as desired. I think I can live with that for the moment.

Comment: Interesting. I've tested the `-c %ArrangeColumn`, and it worked fine on Windows 7.

Comment: curious `-c 1,$ArrangeColumn` works... as well windows 7

Comment: Which Vim version do you use? Some patchlevels of 7.4 had a bug with ranges and user-defined commands.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the function it-self should deal with the whole file.

So to start `gvim`/`vim`/`vi` with command to be executed, you can just call like this:

```
vim -c "call ArrangeColumn()" foo.csv
```

or:

```
vim +"call ArrangeColumn()" foo.csv
```

To save and quit, add `-cwq` parameter.

For example here is the function to remove white spaces from the end of a line:

```
" Removes superfluous white space from the end of a line
function! RemoveWhiteSpace()
    :%s/\s\+$//e
endfunction
```

so you could call:

```
vim +"call RemoveWhiteSpace()" foo.txt
```

Comment: If `ArrangeColumn` were a function, you'd need to prepend `call`; but it's a custom command, so the `()` are wrong.

Comment: I've added `call`, so parentheses are fine now.

Comment: Oh yes. its a command, not a function. Corrected this. But anyway the commands itself does only work on the current line, or if I do a visual selection. I can run it from startup, but then only the first line is affected, but I need all line -> the complete file.

Answer (score 0):

For the actual question: "start file with parameter which executes on the whole file" you can use `autocmd` which runs things on specific triggers for specific filetypes

```
au BufRead *.csv 1,$ArrangeColumn
```

This will run the `ArrangeColumn` command on the entire file `1,$` whenever opening or using '`e`' on a csv file.

Also, you can map a key to re-do it if desired:

```
map AC <C-C>:1,$ArrangeColumn<CR>
```

changing the primary key combo (`AC`) for yourself.

Comment: the `1,$ArrangeColumn` was a good hint. It works now in @ingo's suggestion.